# При попытке вызвать Keras.Models.Model Predict в отдельной задаче вызывает исключение System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, keras

```
Keras.Models.BaseModel model = Keras.Models.Model.LoadModel("keras_model.h5");
bool actionBtn;

void Whl(){
    while (actionBtn){
        Bitmap imbit = GetImageBitmap();
        NDArray ndarray = imbit.ToNDArray(flat: false, copy: true, discardAlpha: true);
        NDArray normalized_image_array = (ndarray.astype(NumSharp.np.float32) / 127.0) - 1;
        float[] fArr = normalized_image_array.ToArray<float>().Select(x => (float)x).ToArray();
        Numpy.NDarray npArr = Numpy.np.array(fArr, Numpy.np.float32).reshape(1, 224, 224, 3);
        var y = model.Predict(npArr);
        y = y.argmax(); 
        Console.WriteLine(y.asscalar<int>().ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

}

private void Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.actionBtn = (bool)sender;
    if (actionBtn)
    {
       Task.Run(()=>Whl());
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пытаетесь обратиться к уже уничтоженному объекту в неуправляемой памяти. Что прешествовало появлению ошибки? Какие действия вы выполнили?

Comment: @aepot по нажатию клавиши запускается задача, но результата Predict нету никакого. Хотя если запускать метод без Task, то все работает

Comment: К примеру, если если запустить этот метод  не как Task то все работает https://pastebin.com/YwkM5xuq

Comment: Почему бы вам не перенести загрузку модели прямо в метод перед циклом? Быть может запуск predict и загрузка модели должны быть в общем потоке?

Comment: @aepot Да, если поместить это в один поток, то все отлично работает

Comment: @aepot Скомпилированный файл вовсе игнорирует теперь строку var y = model.Predict(npArr); и не выдает никаких исключений. В режиме отладки все работает

Comment: Хотя метод  model.PredictOnBatch(npArr); Работает в скомпилированном файле

Comment: Удалите папки bin и obj и пересоберите проект

Comment: @aepot это не помогло